# react-redux shopping-cart example

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to react and react-redux. I am learning the redux example about the Shopping-cart, here is the link [enter link description here](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/tree/master/examples/shopping-cart)

And I have two questions:

1. In `containers/ProductsContainer.js`, the `connect` passed the `{ addToCart }` like this:

```
    import React from 'react'
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
    import { connect } from 'react-redux'
    import { addToCart } from '../actions'
    import { getVisibleProducts } from '../reducers/products'
    import ProductItem from '../components/ProductItem'
    import ProductsList from '../components/ProductsList'
......
    export default connect(
      mapStateToProps,
      { addToCart }
    )(ProductsContainer)
```

I do not understand how the `{ addToCart }` can be passed into `connect`

2.The `addToCard` is like this:

```
export const addToCart = productId => (dispatch, getState) => {
  if (getState().products.byId[productId].inventory > 0) {
     dispatch(addToCartUnsafe(productId))
  }
 }
```

where does `getState` parameter come from?

Comment: `{ addToCart }` is shorthand syntax for writing `{ addToCart: addToCart }`.

Answer (score 1):

Definition of connect function is 
`export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(SomeComponent)`

Here `{ addToCart }` passed directly in place of mapDispatchToProps. It is like `{addToCart : addToCart }` which is called shorthand syntax.